# Append jquery function load multiple content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, append, instagram

i need some suggenstions because i'm going crazy with a little problem about insert data in a html page using append jquery function and ajax request.

I have this html block with different content under ul elements...in `<ul class="pre-wed-list ">` there are some images that i insert directly in html code, instead into `<ul class="pre-wed-list" id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>` i need photos that i catch from my instagram stream ( it is already working ) with ajax request reported below. Here we have html code

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- Nav Tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#pre-wed" aria-controls="pre-wed" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Engagement</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#rudr" aria-controls="#rudr" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">#blabla</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- .nav .nav-tabs -->

                    <!-- Tab Panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" id="pre-wed" class="tab-pane active fade in tab-content-each">
                            <ul class="pre-wed-list ">
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="images/blabla/blabla1.jpg" data-lightbox="pre-wed"><img src='images/blabla/blabla1.jpg' alt="blabla" /></a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" id="rudr" class="tab-pane fade tab-content-each"></div>
                        <ul class="pre-wed-list" id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>
                        </div>
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- .container -->
        </section><!-- .instagram-feed -->
```

Here we have ajax request:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var token = '44386xx.e90c004.xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    num_photos = 10;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for( x in data.data ){
            $("#rudr_instafeed").append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url+'"></li>');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});

    </script>
```

Ajax request works correctly, the content that i need is loaded but the problem is that append jquery function

`$("#rudr_instafeed").append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url+'"></li>');`

charge correctly content photos from instagram stream, but not only in #rudr_instafee ( that i need to have ) but even under my images block in `<ul class="pre-wed-list ">  </ul>` .

I ask to community some helps to solve it, i'm very afraid for it, i don't succeed to solve it :(.

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: you have both class  `pre-wed-list` and  id `rudr_instafeed` on the same `ul`:- `<ul class="pre-wed-list" id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>`. that's why you are seeing it. let me know your point now

Comment: Hi @AlivetoDie, thank you for your answer, i haven't understand where is problem if i have in this ul element with class="pre-wed-list" id="rudr_instafeed", append function need to work only for #rudr_instafeed that is only in this element and not in other.

Thank you

Comment: did you have multiple ul with same class and id both?

Comment: mm no, as you can see in the code, i have two ul elements, but only one has #rudr_instafeed,  used to append in it html content with jquery.

The first ul element has only class="pre-wed-list " ( but append function works even for it ), while second ul ( in which i need to see only in it the content that i append with jquery) has class="pre-wed-list " and id="rudr_instafeedthat" 

are you seeing something i don't view ?

Thank you @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 0):

ok i have solved fortunately, problem was a wrong position for  closing, below html code corrected

```
<div role="tabpanel" id="rudr" class="tab-pane fade tab-content-each">
 <ul class="pre-wed-list" id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>
</div>
```

sometimes too much work and tiredness can make a joke.
Thank you for now.